# Printing a member of a previously added object into a linkedlist

Tags: java

I am relatively new to java programming and i am currently trying to implement a Linked List in Java. I have a class called student. Which has the following members - Name, MarksObtained. Now, i want to add the various student objects to a linked list one by one.

> My_query1: Again, while traversing the list i want to print only the
>   member - MarksObtained.
>
> My_query2: The iterator interface method,
>   itr.next() returns ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*** ?
>
> My_query3: If i create
>   objects of the class student with the same name iteratively and
>   simultaneously add it to the linked list, is it valid?

```
public static void main(String []args){
    LinkedList al = new LinkedList();   
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
           student s = new student();
           s.MarksObtained = i;
           s.Name = "blah";
           al.add(s);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The name of the object you add to the LinkedList isn't important, the fact that you use the `new` operator to create an object every iteration of your loop means that you create a different Student object each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My_query1: Again, while traversing the list i want to print only the member - MarksObtained.

You can traverse the list using the following code, which makes use of the enumerable nature of the list.

```
for (student item : al) {
    System.out.println(item.MarkObtained)
}
```

My_query2: The iterator interface method, itr.next() returns ***_*___** ?

itr.next() returns the next item of the list, according to how you added them to the list (or after sorting, the sorted order). The following code is another way of iterating through the list

```
Iterator<student> itr = al.listIterator(0);
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    student item = itr.next();
    System.out.println(item.MarkObtained);
}
```

My_query3: If i create objects of the class student with the same name iteratively and simultaneously add it to the linked list, is it valid?

Yes this is valid, so long as you "new" each time. If you do not new them but change their member values, all items already added to the list will also change values due to their object reference being the same (so you'll end up as the list full of the item you last added - all the same).

Comment: Okay. So, basically the contents of the object get copied onto the Linked List member and now the only way to access them again is by traversing the list. right?

Comment: Yes, a linked list is not indexable, each element only has a pointer to the next element. You could use other data structures such as an ArrayList to index items directly [ar.get(index)], or a HashMap or TreeMap to index by another identifier, such as their name [map.get(studentname)]. But if you're using a linked list, you have to iterate over it to extract its elements.

Answer (score 0):

> My_query1: Again, while traversing the list

i want to print only the member - MarksObtained.

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
           student s = new student();
           s.MarksObtained = i;
           s.Name = "blah";
           al.add(s);
           System.out.println(s.MarksObtained)

}
```

> My_query2: The iterator interface method, itr.next() returns ***_*___** ?

while iterating it returns the next object under iteration

> If i create objects of the class student with the same name iteratively and simultaneously add it to the linked list, is it valid?

Yes, it is valid

Comment: No, i mean, i wanted to print the MarksObtained while traversing the linkedlist separately by using the iterator interface. possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes in list you can add duplicates.**

```
List<Student> al  =new LinkedList<Student>();

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            Student s = new Student();
            s.marks=i;
            s.name="ABC";
    }

    Iterator<Student> it=al.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {

        Student st=it.next();
        System.out.println(st.name+" , "+st.marks);

    }
```

**Your Answers**

```
My_query1: Again, while traversing the list i want to print only the member - MarksObtained.
```

Yes , you can use Iterator as above.

```
My_query2: The iterator interface method, itr.next() returns __________ ?
```

It returns next object in `Iterator`

```
My_query3: If i create objects of the class student with the same name iteratively and simultaneously add it to the linked list, is it valid?
```

Yes , It is valid .